# Cost function looks like the real math which is responsible for actually working on out problem statement If I talk on a whole and on a surface level?

Tags: deep-learning, loss-function, algorithms

Looking at the cost function for say linear regression, apart from changing the weight or the parameters, the cost function does the real job, right? If it is correct, what does cost function do in Deep Learning then?

Comment: What do you mean that the cost function “does the real job”?

Comment: cost function in linear regression, sort of calcuates the square of the difference between our predictions and the training examples right, which is really helping us in making a concrete hypothesis

Comment: What do you mean by a “concrete hypothesis”?

Comment: hypothesis is basically the relationship we found out about our data right

Comment: You tell me. What do you mean by your terminology, and how does it relate to the cost function?